# How can I get email.utils.make_msgid to pick from address domain instead of local hostname in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to get the message-id to pick the domain portion of the from address and not sure how to do it. I can hardcode it but I would like it pick up whatever the domain portion of the from address

```
message = MIMEMultipart("alternative")
message['From'] = email.utils.formataddr(('User1', 'aniga@domain.com')) # header address
message['Date'] = email.utils.formatdate(timeval=None, localtime=False, usegmt=False)
message['Message-ID'] = email.utils.make_msgid("".join(random.choice("0123456789ABCDEF") for i in range(16)), domain=pickfrom from address domain
message['Subject'] = 'Testing from Python'
message['To'] = email.utils.formataddr((recpient, recpient@example.com))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in support for doing that; if you want to extract the domain part from the `From:` address, you have to do that separately.

There should be no need for you to pick the `idstring` yourself, by the way; let Python take care of that.

You'll probably also want to upgrade to use the Python 3.6+ updated `EmailMessage` API for new code.

```py
from email.message import EmailMessage
import email.utils

message = EmailMessage()
message['From'] = email.utils.formataddr(('User1', 'aniga@domain.com'))
message['Date'] = email.utils.formatdate(timeval=None, localtime=False, usegmt=False)
# Notice change here
message['Message-ID'] = email.utils.make_msgid(domain=message['From'].groups[0].addresses[0].domain)
message['Subject'] = 'Testing from Python'
# Trivial typo + syntax edit here
message['To'] = email.utils.formataddr(('recipient', 'recipient@example.com'))
```

If what you have isn't a `formataddr` it won't have a `groups` attribute; if you simply have a `str` containing the sender's address, a quick and dirty heuristic is to simply split on `@` and take everything up through the first `>` or whitespace character as *probably* the domain name.  But this has a number of pesky corner cases you really want to avoid - it's better to parse the `From:` header (again, if necessary) and be reasonably sure that you really get it properly parsed.

Comment: When i tried your suggestions i am getting the following error `message['Message-ID'] = email.utils.make_msgid(domain=message['From'].groups[0].addresses[0].domain)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'groups'` - any idea

Comment: Works for me (after I fixed the typo I hadn't noticed before); https://ideone.com/6gQwVy Are you on a really old Python version, perhaps?

Comment: i am using 3.8 and still getting same error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'groups'`. If i remove the messageid part the code runs fine.

Comment: Works for me on 3.8.2. The object in `message['From']` needs to be a `formataddr` (like in this code), not a `str`, for the `groups` attribute to exist.

Comment: Probably post a new question about that; feel free to ping me here. Try to prune it down to a [mre] to make it easier to see what's going wrong and to avoid distractions from unrelated problems. Alternatively, just take anything after `@` in the `str` and guess that that can be used as the `domain`.

Comment: thank you very much, your code works when i just print it -  when i use it in the actual  (https://ideone.com/jhEBLq) sending email code it doesn't work. i am not sure where  i am getting wrong.

Comment: The error you get in that is unrelated to anything in the Message-Id code. As of right now, it's displaying `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'html_body.html'` (... you can't upload things to Ideone easily; try to create a wrapper shell script which creates the necessary files in a temporary directory; see e.g. https://ideone.com/0bgM9S for an example).

Comment: I tried to fix obvious problems in your script; https://ideone.com/QerOz5